# discord.py - How do I accept both no arguments and one argument?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to code an economy bot and the beg command requires either no argument or one argument, which should be a user
mention object. How can I accept a command such as: `sov bal` and `sov bal @user`? I've tried passing *args through in the secondary argument (i.e. `x(*args)`), and it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could provide a default value `def command(ctx, user = None)` and then check if user is None in your method

Comment: i'm still glad you provided that i would've been so confused later on in coding lmao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def foo(bar=None):
    if (str(bar)!="None"):
        bar = "default stuff"
```

You don’t need `str(bar)!="None"`.
I have OCD and my coding is highly affected by it.

**Credits to DrummerMann!!!**